# xamarin.forms image appears on all devices, but not on windows10 tablet

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

In my xamarin.forms app I try to put an image on a view. All is well placed and visible on Android emulator, iOS iPad device and WinPhone emulator. But the image does not show on the "local" Win10 machine, nor on the emulator/simulator.
This is the code I use:

**ViewModel:**

```
    using Prism.Mvvm;

    namespace DemoJan017.ViewModels.ViewModels
    {
        public class _StartPageViewModel : BindableBase
        {

            private string _TegelPad;
            public string TegelPad
            {
                get { return _TegelPad; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _TegelPad, value); }
            }



            private string _TegelTekst;
            public string TegelTekst
            {
                get { return _TegelTekst; }
                set { SetProperty(ref _TegelTekst, value); }
            }


            public _StartPageViewModel()

            {
                TegelPad = "Afbeeldingen/Tegels/aanvraag.png";
                TegelTekst = "the first image is visible!";
            }
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoJan017.Views;assembly=DemoJan017"
             xmlns:conv ="clr-namespace:DemoJan017.Common;assembly=DemoJan-17"
             x:Class="DemoJan017.Views._StartPage">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <conv:LocaleAfbeeldingPadConverter
        x:Key="LocaleAfbeeldingPadConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Image Source="{Binding TegelPad, Converter={StaticResource LocaleAfbeeldingPadConverter}}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding TegelTekst}" />
  </StackLayout>  
</ContentPage>
```

**And the converter is like so:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace DemoJan017.Common
    {
        class LocaleAfbeeldingPadConverter:IValueConverter

        {
            private static string _assembly;

            static LocaleAfbeeldingPadConverter()
            {
                _assembly = typeof(LocaleAfbeeldingPadConverter).AssemblyQualifiedName.Split(',')[1].Trim() + '.';
            }


            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                string source = _assembly + ((string)value).Replace('/', '.');
                return ImageSource.FromResource(source);
            }


            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

        }
    }
```

I think I have all references and properties in place, otherwise I don't  think the emulators (for WIN) would not react correctly, or would they?

see the image with the settings:
[image: settings for the solution]

***What is the possible cause of this behaviour?***

Regards

Comment: Can you provide image's path (relative to root) in W10 project? Also, can you give us a path that you use to identify it?

Comment: I have checked your code and found nothing wrong. Could you please try uninstall the app in your machine, clean the solution and redeploy it?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: Before I even post a question here be assured that I have tried trivial options like this - no offence!!

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk: I don't understand what you are looking for. Please reformulate your question so that I better understand what you are after.